# Error when trying to create a Team Project Collection in Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

I can’t seem to get the 1st project collection created in Azure DevOps Server 2019.

The creation process keeps timing out (within an hour range) and stating that it can’t connect to the DB, but it’s clear it’s been connected prior to step #67 in the creation process, which is where it times out.

Here is what I have tried:

Using 2 machines:

One machine has Azure DevOps Server 2019 and SQL 2017 (w/ SSMS) installed with following configuration

- 4G RAM
- At least 12 G free on hard drive now (will be increasing this)

Second machine will house build server

Error from Logs:

> Caught exception in ExecuteScripts: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseRuntimeException:
>   TF246017: Azure DevOps Server could not connect to the database.
>   Verify that the instance is specified correctly, that the server that
>   is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are
>   not blocking communication with the server. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A timeout occurred while waiting
>   for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal'
>   (1). Rerun the query

Comment: Did you create a team project collection when you config DevOps server? Did you type the correct SQL Server instance? Did you test the instance when you config server? Please check the link below to install and config the server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/single-server?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for your response Cece.  I attempted to create the 1st team project collection at the end of the config wizard.  That's when I first received the error.  I then tried to create it from the admin console.  During the configuration wizard, I did test the server and the green checkmark came up to indicate connectivity.  Also, if I go into SSMS, I can see where Azure has created the DBs on each of my attempts.  It just does not finish all it's scripts; it fails at step 67 (out of 387) each time...This is the step where it attempts to 'CreateAnalyticsPartition Schema'.

Comment: @LayatheSCM What the specific version of Azure DevOps 2019 do you have installed? According to the error message, seems there's a database connection issue. Please try to restart the sql server and your Azure DevOps server, then try to create the collection again from the admin console.

Comment: Andy, it's update 1 (ver)...I already tried that solution and it did not fix the issue.  I had an additional  4G RAM installed to the server and that fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had an additional 4G RAM installed to the server and that fixed the issue.